# Finding license dependencies from GitHub repo

Tags: licensing, github

How can I easily determine a project's dependencies' licenses? For example on my GitHub repo which includes multiple open source softwares.

Comment: how is this asking for a tool? what if the answer was "look at this tab".

Comment: Dependencies is a vague concept. Github support reporting deps for Ruby only at this stage. And their detection is kinda crap. Which language are you talking about?

Comment: Can you tell which language you are concerned with?

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using java project build by maven than
  add https://github.com/openCage/loracle-maven-plugin 
into your pom.xml.

It checks whether all licenses of all dependencies (direct and transitive) are 
declared and fit together with your declared license.

note: my project

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, open-source license compliance is a tricky task. There are open source (e.g. [Fossology](https://www.fossology.org)) and proprietary (e.g. [Black Duck's Protex](https://www.blackducksoftware.com/products/protex)) tools assisting you.

It would be so much more easier and convinient if [SPDX](https://spdx.org) becomes a standard for all open-source projects.

Answer (score 1):

The [OSS Review Toolkit](https://github.com/heremaps/oss-review-toolkit)'s [analyzer](https://github.com/heremaps/oss-review-toolkit#analyzer) is designed to do just that. You need to clone your GitHub repo to a local working directory, and then run the analyzer on it as explained in the [getting started](https://github.com/heremaps/oss-review-toolkit/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md) document at the example of the *mime-types* project.

*Disclaimer:* I'm the founder and lead developer of the OSS Review Toolkit (ORT).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not always so easy. Some dependencies have a mix of files with different licenses, and they are difficult to find.

Just as an example: When you look at org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto it clearly seems to be an Apache 2.0 licensed library. However it includes 1 file which is under ISC license: BCrypt.java

I think it is difficult to determine how much diligence developers have to show in searching/finding cases like this in dependencies of their software, or if it is enough to rely on the declarations of the project itself in the repository.

[I know the question is old, but still want to add my 2c]

Answer (score -2):

For example, look at [this](https://github.com/otale/tale) project

You can see it here：

[image]

Open https://github.com/otale/tale/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: That displays the license of the project, not the project's dependencies.